# Edit request data before validation

Tags: php, laravel

> Request data:

```
    [
        "invoice_data" => [
            ...
            "discount" => null,
        ],
        "product_credit" => [
            ...
            "discount" => null,
        ]
    ];
```

> What I am trying to do

I am trying to create an `if statement` to check if the

`$request -> invoice_data['discount'] == null` then set it to **0** ALSO

`$request -> product_credit['discount'] == null` then set it to **0**

***Before the validation process because the validation will fail.***

> What I have tried:

I have found a method in Laravel called `prepareForValidation()` and it use `$this -> merge([...])` which is what I am looking for but problem is that I cannot access the discount in `invoice_data` and `product_credit`.

Comment: Not familiar with laravel, but i would search for something like "middleware" to manipulate the request

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner way to set a default value of attributes than editing in request payload:

```
Model {
   protected $attributes = [
      'inovice_data' => 0,
      'discount' => 0,
      'product_credit' => 0
   ];
}
```

In this way, if no values are provided, or undefined value or null, Eloquent will set these attributes to defined default values while populating in db.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data =
[
        "invoice_data" => [
            "discount" => null,
        ],
        "product_credit" => [
            "discount" => null,
        ]
    ];

$keyWhitelist = [
    'invoice_data',
    'product_credit'
];

foreach ($data as $key => $entry) {

    if(!in_array($key, $keyWhitelist)) {
        continue;
    }

    if(key_exists('discount',$entry)) {
        if ($entry['discount'] === null) {
            $data[$key]['discount'] = 0;
        }
    }
}

var_export($data);
```

gives result:

```
array (
  'invoice_data' => 
  array (
    'discount' => 0,
  ),
  'product_credit' => 
  array (
    'discount' => 0,
  ),
)
```